# Match string prefixes with different length

Tags: string, rust, pattern-matching

I am trying to tokenize boolean algebra, so I need to check if the start of a `str` matches a list of tokens (e.g. `AND`, `OR`, etc.). `str.startsWith` in an if else would obviously work, but it is an ugly solution, so I am wondering if theres a way to match an str like

```rust
match st {
  "OR", .. => ...
}
```

(obviously not real syntax)

Also: I can not rely on whitespaces or other characters following the String, `ABxxxx` should not match, while `ORxxxxx` should match.

Comment: You could do something like this: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=31be791fb35b8167425e041a1231cb0a

Comment: That would definetly work, Ill use that while I wait for a more elegant solution that im not even sure exists

Comment: I have created a proc macro for your solution: https://gist.github.com/downloadpizza/1ac14b0a7e65371d45baf333fca0b349 Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think if you only need to match a few strings, then an `if ... else if` tree or Martin's solution is probably best. Otherwise, I don't think there is a way to match string slice prefixes using `match`.

If, however, you have many strings you need to match, I'd recommend `AhoCorasick`, which will be algorithmically optimal. You can use the [`aho-corasick` crate](https://crates.io/crates/aho-corasick).

```
use aho_corasick::{AhoCorasick, AhoCorasickBuilder, MatchKind};

const PATTERNS: &[&str] = &["OR", "AND"];

fn op<T: AsRef<[u8]>>(ac: &AhoCorasick, v: T) -> Option<&'static str> {
    ac.find(v).map(|m| PATTERNS[m.pattern()])
}

fn main() {
    let ac = AhoCorasickBuilder::new()
        .auto_configure(PATTERNS)
        .anchored(true)
        .match_kind(MatchKind::LeftmostFirst)
        .build(PATTERNS);
    println!(
        "{:?} / {:?} / {:?}",
        op(&ac, "OR"),
        op(&ac, "AND"),
        op(&ac, "XOR")
    )
}
```

The trick to make it work for prefixes here is to set `anchored(true)`. This will ensure that any match returned must be anchored to the beginning of the haystack.

The `LeftmostFirst` match kind setting may not be necessary, but it instructs the matcher to prefer earlier patterns over later patterns. e.g., if your patterns are `Samwise` and `Sam`, then `LeftmostFirst` will ensure that `Samwise` matches `Samwise` and not `Sam`. If none of your patterns have overlapping prefixes, then you can remove this setting.

Finally, the `auto_configure` option will enable some optimizations in the automaton, such as using a DFA instead of an NFA if the number of patterns is small enough.

[See it also on the playground.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=6ce8de3173b2e7091b9faf7bfa52b7b0)